# Signed/unsigned mismatch and function does not take 2 arguments when converting to function

Tags: c++, function, unsigned

So i was able to write a program that will convert a string into morse code, but the teacher wants the converting part in a function, which i did, but it gives the errors of 
warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch n line 29
and
error C2660: 'toMorse' : function does not take 2 arguments on line 18
And you would think after being able to get the normal program working this would be a cinch but my brain is dead at this point. Any help on finding out why its doing this would be greatly appreciated, though i guess i could turn in the assignment with it all in main{} wouldnt be too bad.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

// Function Prototypes
string toMorse(char);

int main()
{

    string userInput;

    cout << "Please input a string to convert to morse code." << endl;
    getline(cin, userInput, '\n');

    int stringSize = userInput.length();

    toMorse(userInput, stringSize);

}

//*****************************************************************
//Function to convert into morse code
//*****************************************************************
string toMorse(string morseArray, int stringSize)
{
    string *toConvert = new string[stringSize];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < stringSize; i += 1)
    {
        if (toupper(userInput.at(i)) == 'A')
        toConvert[i] = ".-";
    // will fill in the rest once problems are solved
        else toConvert[i] = " ";
    }

    for (size_t x = 0; x < stringSize; x += 1)
        cout << toConvert[x] << "  ";

    cout << endl;

    delete[] toConvert;

    return 0;
}
```

So I was able to get it working from the tips given, but now every time i run the following code (it translates correctly, just when i hit enter it shows the right input but also says "Debug Assertion Failed! Expression: invalid null pointer on MSVCP120D.dll line 1168"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

// Function Prototypes
string toMorse(string, size_t);

int main()
{

    string userInput;

    cout << "Please input a string to convert to morse code." << endl;
    getline(cin, userInput, '\n');

    int stringSize = userInput.length();

    toMorse(userInput, stringSize);

}

//*****************************************************************
//Function to convert into morse code
//*****************************************************************
string toMorse(string morseArray, size_t stringSize)
{
    string *toConvert = new string[stringSize];

    for (size_t i = 0; i < stringSize; i += 1)
    {
        if (toupper(morseArray.at(i)) == ' ')
            toConvert[i] = " ";
        else if (toupper(morseArray.at(i)) == ',')
            toConvert[i] = "--..--";
        else if (toupper(morseArray.at(i)) == '.')
            toConvert[i] = ".-.-.-";
        else if (toupper(morseArray.at(i)) == '?')
            toConvert[i] = "..--..";
        else if (morseArray.at(i) == '0')
            toConvert[i] = "-----";
        else if (morseArray.at(i) == '1')
            toConvert[i] = ".----";
        else if (morseArray.at(i) == '2')
            toConvert[i] = "..---";
        else if (morseArray.at(i) == '3')
            toConvert[i] = "...--";
        else if (morseArray.at(i) == '4')
            toConvert[i] = "....-";
        else if (morseArray.at(i) == '5')
            toConvert[i] = ".....";
        else if (morseArray.at(i) == '6')
            toConvert[i] = "-....";
        else if (morseArray.at(i) == '7')
            toConvert[i] = "--...";
        else if (morseArray.at(i) == '8')
            toConvert[i] = "---..";
        else if (morseArray.at(i) == '9')
            toConvert[i] = "----.";
        else if (toupper(morseArray.at(i)) == 'A')
            toConvert[i] = ".-";
        else if (toupper(morseArray.at(i)) == 'B')
            toConvert[i] = "-...";
        else if (toupper(morseArray.at(i)) == 'C')
            toConvert[i] = "-.-.";
        else if (toupper(morseArray.at(i)) == 'D')
            toConvert[i] = "-..";
        else if (toupper(morseArray.at(i)) == 'E')
            toConvert[i] = ".";
        else if (toupper(morseArray.at(i)) == 'F')
            toConvert[i] = "..-.";
        else if (toupper(morseArray.at(i)) == 'G')
            toConvert[i] = "--.";
        else if (toupper(morseArray.at(i)) == 'H')
            toConvert[i] = "....";
        else if (toupper(morseArray.at(i)) == 'I')
            toConvert[i] = "..";
        else if (toupper(morseArray.at(i)) == 'J')
            toConvert[i] = ".---";
        else if (toupper(morseArray.at(i)) == 'K')
            toConvert[i] = "-.-";
        else if (toupper(morseArray.at(i)) == 'L')
            toConvert[i] = ".-..";
        else if (toupper(morseArray.at(i)) == 'M')
            toConvert[i] = "--";
        else if (toupper(morseArray.at(i)) == 'N')
            toConvert[i] = "-.";
        else if (toupper(morseArray.at(i)) == 'O')
            toConvert[i] = "---";
        else if (toupper(morseArray.at(i)) == 'P')
            toConvert[i] = ".--.";
        else if (toupper(morseArray.at(i)) == 'Q')
            toConvert[i] = "--.-";
        else if (toupper(morseArray.at(i)) == 'R')
            toConvert[i] = ".-.";
        else if (toupper(morseArray.at(i)) == 'S')
            toConvert[i] = "...";
        else if (toupper(morseArray.at(i)) == 'T')
            toConvert[i] = "-";
        else if (toupper(morseArray.at(i)) == 'U')
            toConvert[i] = "..-";
        else if (toupper(morseArray.at(i)) == 'V')
            toConvert[i] = "...-";
        else if (toupper(morseArray.at(i)) == 'W')
            toConvert[i] = ".--";
        else if (toupper(morseArray.at(i)) == 'X')
            toConvert[i] = "-..-";
        else if (toupper(morseArray.at(i)) == 'Y')
            toConvert[i] = "-.--";
        else if (toupper(morseArray.at(i)) == 'Z')
            toConvert[i] = "--..";
        else toConvert[i] = " ";
    }

    for (size_t x = 0; x < stringSize; x += 1)
        cout << toConvert[x] << "  ";

    cout << endl;

    delete[] toConvert;

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks so much. I was able to get it running with no errors by changing it to a proper return type. Thanks again. And thanks to you all for the help!

Comment: The prototype before `main` differs from the function's prototype.

Comment: In the definition of `toMorse`, you've defined `i` as `size_t` (which is unsigned) and `stringSize` as `int` (which is signed), so the `i < stringSize` in your `for` loop compares a signed to an unsigned, with possibly unexpected results.

Comment: Having C++: Avoid signed indices, you rarely need these - although a lot of code uses signed (and fix all warnings regarding signed/unsigned).

Answer (score 0):

C4018 warning is about comparison. You can use function prototype like:

```
string toMorse(string morseArray, size_t stringSize);
```

Also you've define `toMorse` function as `string toMorse(char);` in the beginning of the file and this is different from what you have below.

Answer (score 0):

One more error - line `userInput` should say `morseArray` in `if (toupper(userInput.at(i)) == 'A')`.

Also why would you initialize the for loop with `size_t i = 0` instead of `int i = 0`?

Comment: `size_t` is a better option here because the value could go from `0` to the maximum length of a string. The string could be longer than `INT_MAX`.

Comment: I get the usage is size_t, but my point is that the code bit looks inconsistent `for (size_t i = 0; i < stringSize; i += 1)`. `i` is `size_t`, `stringSize` is `int` and increment of `i` is unconventional.

Comment: `stringSize` has been changed to `size_t` now (although it is redundant as strings know their size)

Answer (score 0):

In the updated version, the `toMorse` function is defined to have `string` as return type.

However you wrote `return 0;`. This constructs a string using `0` as argument, which is treated as a null pointer. (This is a hangover from C). This causes undefined behaviour which is manifesting itself as "Debug assertion failed".  The constructor of `string` which takes a pointer expects that to be a pointer to some characters.

To fix this either change the function to return `void`, or return a valid string.  The function name suggests it is supposed to return the morse code string, instead of sending it to `cout`.

Comment: Thanks so much. I was able to get it running with no errors by changing it to a proper return type. Thanks again. And thanks to you all for the help!